# Laravel - Point all route requests to single view or function

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I have a master view and want all my GET routes return the same every time.
E.g

```
Route::get('/user', function() {
  view('layout');
});
Route::get('/user/add', function() {
  view('layout');
});
```

How to write a single route function so that returns layout view every time? It means in any case or any number of parameters passed, it should always return layout view.

Comment: you can add `Route::get('/user/{any}' ... `

Comment: yes but in that case `/user` has to be hardcoded. I want to avoid it.

Comment: You can just use `'/{any}'` without user. Wondering why you want to do that, its strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in your route definition. This will hit on all routes.

```
Route::get('/{route?}', function() {
  view('layout');
});
```

A better approach in my opinion is to look how `CMS` structures do it. And do it with sections of the `URL` and you can handle it for more customization.

```
Route::get('/{model?}/{action?}', function($model, $action) {
    if ($model === 'user') {
        return view('user', compact('action'));
    } 

    return view('default');
});
```